# Rails devise not showing authentication error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Devise showing errors for signup correctly, but not for signin. I am using username instead of email. When I try to login with wrong username/password, it shows an empty error array

```
{"error"=>""}
```

Here is the controller code:

```
class LoginsessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  skip_before_action :verify_signed_out_user


  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    redirect_to '/login', :alert => { :error => @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ') }
  end
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:username, :remember_me])
  end
  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   root_path
end
end
```

Model user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, authentication_keys: [:username]
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, uniqueness: true

end
```

And login.html.erb

```
<div class="form-app">
        <%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, :class => "input", :placeholder => "Username" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "input", :placeholder => "Password" %>
        <% if Devise.mappings[:user].rememberable? -%>
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
            <%= f.label :remember_me %>
          </div>
        <% end -%>
        <%= f.submit "Sign In", :class => "login" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you add some more code regarding your use of Devise? this is of little help.

Comment: some more context would be helpful and I would suggest using pry to throw breakpoints around. That usually helps me solve issues like this.